# Server script unable to find parts in workspace

Tags: roblox

I'm making a PvP game and have a fireball ability. I'm trying to destroy the fireball after it touches a humanoid however, the script is unable to find the fireball part in the workspace and gives an infinite yield warning.

This is the code creating the fireball object:

```
if Input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.Q  then
    if debounce == true then return end
    debounce = true
    local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
    local lookdirection = player.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame.LookVector
    
    
    
    print(player, "uses Fireball")
    local fireball = game.ReplicatedStorage.Animations.FireBall.Fireball:Clone()
    fireball.Parent = workspace.Temp
    fireball.CFrame = player.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame * CFrame.new(0,0,-2)
    fireball.AssemblyLinearVelocity = lookdirection * 50
    fireball:SetAttribute("Owner", player.Name)
    
    local Force = Instance.new("BodyForce")

    Force.Force = Vector3.new(0, workspace.Gravity * fireball:GetMass() , 0)
    Force.Parent = fireball
    
    game.ReplicatedStorage.FireBall:FireServer(fireball.Size, fireball.CFrame, fireball.AssemblyLinearVelocity)
    
    wait(cooldown)
    debounce = false
    
end
```

When the player presses Q, the script clones a part from ReplicatedStorage and puts it in the workspace.Temp folder, then it fires the Fireball RemoteEvent.

Here is the code for the RemoteEvent:

```lua
game.ReplicatedStorage.FireBall.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    
    local fireball = game.Workspace.Temp:WaitForChild("Fireball")
    local hitbox = Instance.new("Part")
    hitbox.Parent = workspace.Hitboxes
    hitbox.Anchored = false
    hitbox.CanCollide = false
    hitbox.Transparency = 0.5
    hitbox.Size = fireball.Size
    hitbox.CFrame = fireball.CFram
    hitbox.AssemblyLinearVelocity = fireball.AssemblyLinearVelocity
    local Force = Instance.new("BodyForce")

    Force.Force = Vector3.new(0, workspace.Gravity * hitbox:GetMass() , 0)
    Force.Parent = hitbox
    

    --workspace.Temp:WaitForChild("Fireball").CFrame
    game.Debris:AddItem(hitbox, 2)

    local Hits = {}
    hitbox.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
        if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") and hit.Parent.Name ~= player.Name then
            if Hits[hit.Parent.Name] then
                return
            end

            if hit.Parent:GetAttribute("Block")  then
                print(hit.Parent.Name, "blocks the attack")
            else

                print(hit.parent.Name, ("HIT BY FIREBALL"))
                hit.Parent.Humanoid:TakeDamage(10)

            end

            Hits[hit.Parent.Name] = true
            hitbox:Destroy()
            fireball:Destroy()
            
            wait(4)
        end
    end)

end)
```

I tried to pass the fireball object itself into the RemoteEvent however, I couldn't get that to work and couldn't find a direct answer on if it was possible online, So instead
I have the WaitForChild method looking for the object within workspace but as said before, it just returns an infinite yield. I can see the fireball object in the folder when in-game and I'm positive the spelling is correct so I'm a bit clueless atm.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this is not working is because you are creating the fireball on the client, then on the server trying to get it from the folder. This will not work since, to combat exploits, if you create an instance on the client it will not replicate to the server.

Since the Part isn't replicated WaitForChild will yeild Indefinitely.

You can instead of creating the fireball on the client, you should call the RemoteEvent, then the server should create the fireball instance.

An Added note, you can pass instances through RemoteEvents, as long as the instance is replicated on both client and server.

Comment: ahh okay, that makes sense i didn't realise it was client only. thanks for the help